# Как сделать чтобы при смене слайда видео останавливалось

Tags: javascript, swiper

Всем привет использую Swiper 5.3.8 в слайдах есть автоматическая загрузка видео, все работает, но проблема в том, что при изменении слайда, слайд который перестал быть активным все равно проигрывает видео, как сделать так, чтоб видео останавливалось. Когда слайд перестает быть активным